# ATM Machine customers.txt file

Tags: java, filereader

I'm a new user in stack overflow.. okay so I'm doing an `ATM` Java program.. my problem is, I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to make a **file reader** (mine is `customers.txt`) in my `ATMSimulator.java`..

Here is my `ATM.java` :

```
/*
An ATM that accesses a bank.
*/

public class ATM
{
public static final int CHECKING = 1;
public static final int SAVINGS = 2;

private int state;
private int customerNumber;
private Customer currentCustomer;
private BankAccount currentAccount;
private Bank theBank;

public static final int START = 1;
public static final int PIN = 2;
public static final int ACCOUNT = 3;
public static final int TRANSACT = 4;

/*
    Construct an ATM for a given bank.
    @param aBank the bank to which this ATM connects
*/

public ATM (Bank aBank)
{
    theBank = aBank;
    reset();
}

/*
    Resets the ATM to the initial state
*/

public void reset()
{
    customerNumber = -1;
    currentAccount = null;
    state = START;
}

/*
    Sets the current customer number and sets state to PIN.
    (Precondition: state is START)
    @param number the customer number
*/

public void setCustomerNumber (int number)
{
    assert state == START;
    customerNumber = number;
    state = PIN;
}

/*
    Finds customer in bank. If found, sets state to ACCOUNT, else to START
    (Precondition: state is PIN)
    @param pin the PIN of the current customer
*/

public void selectCustomer (int pin)
{
    assert state == PIN;
    currentCustomer = theBank.findCustomer (customerNumber, pin);

    if (currentCustomer == null)
        state = START;
    else
        state = ACCOUNT;
}

/*
    Sets current account to checking or savings. Sets state to TRANSACT.
    (Precondition: state is ACCOUNT or TRANSACT)
    @param account one of CHECKING or SAVINGS
*/

public void selectAccount (int account)
{
    assert state == ACCOUNT || state == TRANSACT;

    if (account == CHECKING )
        currentAccount = currentCustomer.getCheckingAccount ();
    else
        currentAccount = currentCustomer.getSavingsAccount();
    state = TRANSACT;
}

/*
    Withdraws amount from current account.
    (Precondition state is TRANSACT)
    @param value the amount to withdraw
*/

public void withdraw (double value)
{
    assert state == TRANSACT;
    currentAccount.withdraw(value);
}

/*
    Deposits amount to current account.
    (Prcondition: state is TRANSACT)
    @param value the amount to deposit
*/

public void deposit (double value)
{
    assert state == TRANSACT;
    currentAccount.deposit (value);
}

/*
    Gets the balance of the current account.
    (Precondition: state is TRANSACT)
    @return the balance
*/

public double getBalance()
{
    assert state == TRANSACT;
    return currentAccount.getBalance();
}

/*
    Moves back to previous state
*/

public void back ()
{
    if (state == TRANSACT)
        state = ACCOUNT;
    else if (state == ACCOUNT)
        state = PIN;
    else if (state == PIN)
        state = START;
}

/*
    Gets the current state of this ATM.
    @return the currnt state
*/

public int getState ()
{
    return state;
}
}
```

Here is my `Customer.java` :

```
/*
A bank customer with a checking and a savings account.
*/

public class Customer
{
private int customerNumber;
private int pin;
private BankAccount checkingAccount;
private BankAccount savingsAccount;

/*
    Construct a customer with a given number and PIN.
    @param aNumber the customer number
    @param aPin the personal identification number
*/

public Customer (int aNumber, int aPin)
{
    customerNumber = aNumber;
    pin = aPin;
    checkingAccount = new BankAccount();
    savingsAccount = new BankAccount();
}

/*
    Test if this customer matches a customer number and PIN
    @param aNumber a customer number
    @param aPin a personal identification number
    @return true if the customer number and PIN match
*/

public boolean match (int aNumber, int aPin)
{
    return customerNumber == aNumber && pin == aPin;
}

/*
    Gets the checking account of this customer
    @return the checking account
*/

public BankAccount getCheckingAccount()
{
    return checkingAccount;
}

/*
    Get the savings account of this customer
    @return checking account
*/

public BankAccount getSavingsAccount()
{
    return savingsAccount;
}
}
```

Here is my `Bank.java` :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

/*
A bank contains customer with bank accounts
*/

public class Bank
{
private ArrayList<Customer> customers;

/*
    Construct a bank with no customers
*/

public Bank()
{
    customers = new ArrayList<Customer> ();
}

/*
    Reads the customer numbers and pins
    and initializes the bank accounts
    @param filename the name of the customer file
*/

public void readCustomers(String filename)
    throws IOException
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner (new File(filename));

    while (in.hasNext())
    {
        int number = in.nextInt();
        int pin = in.nextInt();
        Customer c = new Customer (number, pin);
        addCustomer (c);
    }
    in.close();
}

/*
    Adds a customer to the bank.
    @param c the customer to add
*/

public void addCustomer (Customer c)
{
    customers.add(c);
}

/*
    Find a customer in the bank.
    @param aNumber a customer number
    @param aPin a personal identification number
    @return the matching customer, or null if no customer matches
*/

public Customer findCustomer (int aNumber, int aPin)
{
    for (Customer c : customers)
    {
        if (c.match(aNumber, aPin))
            return c;
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Here is my `BankAccount.java` :

```
/**
A bank account has a balance that can be changed by deposits and withdrawals
*/
public class BankAccount
{
private int accountNumber;
private double balance;

/**
    Counstruct a bank account with a zero balance.
    @param anAccountNumber the account number for this account
*/

public BankAccount(){}


public BankAccount(int anAccountNumber)
{
    accountNumber = anAccountNumber;
    balance = 0;
}

/**
    Construct a bank account with a given balance.
    @param anAccountNumber the account number for this account
    @param initialBalance the initial balance
*/
public BankAccount(int anAccountNumber, double initialBalance)
{
    accountNumber = anAccountNumber;
    balance = initialBalance;
}

/**
    Gets the account number of this bank account.
    @return the account number
*/
public int getAccountNumber()
{
    return accountNumber;
}

/**
    Deposits money into bank account
    @param amount the amount to deposit
*/
public void deposit (double amount)
{
    double newBalance = balance + amount;
    balance = newBalance;
}

/**
    Withdraws money from the bank account.
    @param amount the amount to withdraw
*/
public void withdraw(double amount)
{
    double newBalance = balance - amount;
    balance = newBalance;
}

/**
    Gets the current balance of the bank account.
    @return the current balance
*/
public double getBalance()
{
    return balance;
}
}
```

And I'm having a problem with `customers.txt` in `ATMSimulator.java`:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

/*
    A text based simulation of an automatic teller machine.
*/

public class ATMSimulator
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
{
    ATM theATM;

    try
    {
        Bank theBank = new Bank ();
        theBank.readCustomers("customers.txt");
        theATM = new ATM (theBank);
    }

    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println ("Error opening accounts file.");
        return;
    }

    Scanner in= new Scanner (System.in);

    while (true)
    {
        int state = theATM.getState();
        if (state == ATM.START)
        {
            System.out.print ("Enter customer number: ");
            int number = in.nextInt();
            theATM.setCustomerNumber(number);
        }

        else if (state == ATM.PIN)
        {
            System.out.println ("Enter PIN: ");
            int pin = in.nextInt();
            theATM.setCustomerNumber (pin);
        }

        else if (state == ATM.ACCOUNT )
        {
            System.out.print ("A = Checking, B = Savings, C = Quit: ");
            String command = in.next();

            if (command.equalsIgnoreCase ("A"))
                theATM.selectAccount (ATM.CHECKING);
            else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase ("B"))
                theATM.selectAccount (ATM.SAVINGS);
            else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase ("C"))
                theATM.reset();
            else
                System.out.println ("Illegal input!");
        }

        else if (state == ATM.TRANSACT)
        {
            System.out.println ("Balance = " + theATM.getBalance());
            System.out.print ("A = Deposit, B = Withdrawal, C = Cancel: ");
            String command = in.next();

            if (command.equalsIgnoreCase ("A"))
            {
                System.out.print ("Amount: ");
                double amount = in.nextDouble();
                theATM.deposit (amount);
                theATM.back();
            }

        else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase ("B"))
        {
            System.out.print ("Amount: ");
            double amount = in.nextDouble();
            theATM.withdraw (amount);
            theATM.back();
        }

        else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase ("C"))
            theATM.back();

        else
            System.out.println ("Illegal input!");
        }
    }
}
}
```

**I had created the `customers.txt` file, but the output is error**.. please help me

Comment: and the error being?

Comment: it will print "Error opening accounts file."

If I create customers.txt file, it will show java.util.InputMismatchException

Comment: If you made that error the main point of the question, it would have been helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'll address your **question** not the sh.. big amount of code.

You efficiently read from file in this way.

```
try( BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filename.txt"))){  
   String line;
   while((line = br.readLine()) != null){

   }
}catch(IOException e}{
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If you wish to read from console:

```
try( BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))){  
   String line;
   while((line = br.readLine()) != null){

   }
}catch(IOException e}{
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

To indicate the end of input in the console use `ctrl + z`.

Comment: sorry sir, I don't understand.. for my case, how to make the "filename.txt" ?

Comment: @Lufiii Please show the exception stack you get and mark the place you get it in your code, by comment //EXCEPTION HERE for example. This will help a lot.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
 at Bank.readCustomers(Bank.java:37)
 at ATMSimulator.main(ATMSimulator.java:17)

Comment: sorry sir, I'm so newbie in java

Answer (score 0):

Hey so the path for the text file you passed in the method readCustomer is not the right path. So what you can do is put in src and package name in the path as follows: "src/packageName/customer.txt"

so when you call it in your main it would be

```
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    ATM theATM;

    try
    {
        Bank theBank = new Bank ();
        theBank.readCustomers("src/packageName/customer.txt");
        theATM = new ATM (theBank);
    }
```

Hope this helps.